# Verb question: 'check' vs. 'check out' in an invitation

Tags: word-choice

I have to make an invitation to some people. Is it correct to say "come check out our products" or "come check our products"?

Comment: Hi lauren, welcome to EL&U! Your first question isn't bad, but you may benefit from taking the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or visiting our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help). Offhand the edits I would recommend you make would be making your question title more descriptive (simply reading that tells us nothing about your question), using blockquotes to separate your sentence choices, and letting us know what research you've already done. - [From Review](http://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/172907)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely the first one - "come check out our products."

"Come check our products" comes with the sense that you want them to examine or critique your products in some way, or make sure they're up to some standard, rather than to come as customers with genuine curiosity.